# Accurately Documenting Dates of Attendance at Previous Institutions for Ph.D. Applications

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am in the process of applying to Ph.D. programs and I am asked to list my previous institutions along with dates attended. It should be a straightforward question but in my situation: I attended institution X from 2013-2015, got an A.A., then went to institution Y from 2015-2017 for my B.S., but in between I took classes at institution X over the Summer of 2016. Institution X is in my hometown and I was there over the Summer of 2016, so it was convenient to knock out some credits while back home.

Because of this, it is also a bit confusing as to whether I should list my GPA from institution X at the degree confer date, or to list my cumulative GPA (which factors in the classes I took over the 2016 Summer), as both show up on my transcript. It seems like a minor issue but I want to make sure it doesn't appear as if I'm misleading the admissions committee in any way. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Edit: The format on most applications is: "Date Attended: From-- to--" without the option of listing several date ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The format on most applications is: "Date Attended: From-- to--" without the option of listing several date ranges.

Just put your earliest attended date to your latest, unless it specifically asks for dates related to your AA. Don't overthink it!

> Because of this, it is also a bit confusing as to whether I should list my GPA from institution X at the degree confer date, or to list my cumulative GPA

Again, unless it specifically asks for your AA GPA, I would list your cumulative (I assume it's not much different in any case).

Details of your associate's degree are not going to be a deciding factor in your PhD admissions. Plus, it's likely your transcript lists your AA and cumulative GPA separately anyway (mine from my four-year undergraduate university does), if they truly care.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you!